# Need assistance setting up reverse proxy using Docker and Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, apache-superset

I installed Superset using Docker and am trying to setup reverse proxy using Nginx to utilize HTTPS with a cert from our CA. I am currently getting the following error: PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed. Seems like it is not able to authenticate the key. Can anyone assist with this issue?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your nginx config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your private key have a passphrase on it? If so, try this on your key file:

```
openssl rsa -in with_pass.pem -out without_pass.pem
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! I also had the .pem and .key files under a home user account directory. I moved them to /etc/ssl/certs.